# Get value after finding the object and comparing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

in database :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f699be094b2ee07a3590"),
    "USERNAME" : "dawdwa",
    "PASSWORD" : "dwaawaw"
}
```

in c# code :

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("USERNAME", "dawdwa");
 var doc = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I get the Passwork value when searching through the Username key above.
I get the username value the user entered. Then I look for the object with the username as above, how can I get the password when I find the other username to compare.
sorry for my english. thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you need to find PASSWORD by USERNAME?

Comment: I have solved that problem.

Comment: var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("USERNAME", inputName);
var doc = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
doc.GetElement(2).Value.ToString()  and compare inputPass vs doc.GetElement(2).Value.ToString()

Comment: I still don't understand what you wanted to do, but anyway it's better to use: `doc["whatever"]` instead of this way `doc.GetElement(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you model the document as a C# class you'll be able to just use normal properties once you've got the document out of the database.

```cs
class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("USERNAME")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("PASSWORD")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("users");

var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Username, "dwaawaw");

var results = await collection.Find(filter)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    // You'll be able to access password through the `Password` property
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Id}, {result.Username}, {result.Password}");
}
```

This also has the advantage you'll have more type-safe queries.